# In Perl, how can I remove all spaces that are not inside double quotes " "?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm tying to come up with some regex that will remove all space chars from a string as long as it's not inside of double quotes (").

Example string:

**some string with "text in quotes"**

Result:

**somestringwith"text in quotes"**

So far I've come up with something like this:

```
    $str =~ /"[^"]+"|/g;
```

But it doesn't seem to be giving the intended result.

I'm honestly very new at perl and haven't had too much regexp experience. So if anyone willing to answer would also be willing to provide some insight into the why and how that would be great!

Thanks!

**EDIT**

String will not contain escaped "'s

It should actually always be formatted like this:

**Some.String = "Some Value"**

Result would be

**Some.String="Some Value"**

Comment: Can you have escaped quotes inside the quotes? E.g. `"text in \"quotes\""`.

Comment: No, string is actually always going to be in this form. Some.String.Info = "Some Text in Quotes". There may be some escaped ' however. Ex: "Some String wouldn\'t"

Comment: What if the string is: **some string with "quotes and then" some "more quotes"**?

Comment: @ArjunShankar Shouldn't happen but it may be possible. If that was the case it would look like this. Some.String = "Some Value" Another.String = "Another Value"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a technique using `split` to separate the quoted strings. It relies on your data being consistent and will not work with loose quotes.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @line = split /("[^"]*")/;
for (@line) {
    unless (/^"/) {
        s/[ \t]+//g;
    }
}
print @line;  # line is altered
```

Basically, you split up the string in order to isolate the quoted strings. Once that is done, perform the substitution on all other strings. Since the array elements are aliased in the loop, substitutions are performed on the actual array.

You can run this script like so:

```
perl -n script.pl inputfile
```

To see the output. Or

```
perl -n -i.bak script.pl inputfile
```

To do in-place edit on `inputfile`, while saving backup in `inputfile.bak`.

With that said, I'm not sure what your edit means. Do you want to change

```
Some.String = "Some Value"
```

to

```
Some.String="Some Value"
```

Answer (score 3):

[Text::ParseWords](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text%3a%3aParseWords) is tailor-made for this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::ParseWords;

my @strings = (
    q{This.string = "Hello World"},
    q{That " string " and "another   shoutout to my   bytes"},
);

for my $s ( @strings ) {
    my @words = quotewords '\s+', 1, $s;
    print join('', @words), "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
This.string="Hello World"
That" string "and"another   shoutout to my   bytes"
```

Using `Text::ParseWords` means if you ever had to deal with quoted strings with escaped quotation marks in them, you'd be ready ;-)

Also, this sounds like you have a configuration file of some sort and you're trying to parse it. If that is the case, there are probably better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest removing the quoted substrings using `split` and then recombining them with `join` after removing whitespace from the intermediate text.

Note that if the regex used for `split` contains captures then the captured values will also be included in the list returned.

Here's some sample code.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $source = <<END;
Some.String = "Some Value";
Other.String = "Other Value";
Last.String = "Last Value";
END

print join '', map {s/\s+// unless /"/; $_; } split /("[^"]*")/, $source;
```

**output**

```
Some.String= "Some Value";Other.String = "Other Value";Last.String = "Last Value";
```

Comment: `join` is redundant in void (print) context here, unless `$,` is set to some defined value. A more illuminating example might be assigning the `join` statement to a scalar.

Comment: Your substitution should include the g (global) modifier.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply loop through the string char by char. This way you can handle escaped strings too (just add an isEscaped variable).

```
my $text='lala "some thing with quotes " lala ... ';
my $quoteOpen = 0;
my $out;

foreach $char(split//,$text) {
  if ($char eq "\"" && $quoteOpen==0) {
    $quoteOpen = 1;
    $out .= $char;
  } elsif ($char eq "\"" && $quoteOpen==1) {
    $quoteOpen = 0;
    $out .= $char;
  } elsif ($char =~ /\s/ && $quoteOpen==1) {
    $out .= $char;
  } elsif ($char !~ /\s/) {
    $out .= $char;
  }
}

print "$out\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Splitting on double quotes, removing spaces only from even fields (i.e. those in quotes):

```
sub remove_spaces {
    my $string = shift;
    my @fields = split /"/, $string . ' '; # trailing space needed to keep final " in output
    my $flag = 1;
    return join '"', map { s/ +//g if $flag; $flag = ! $flag; $_} @fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with regex:

```
s/([^ ]*|\"[^\"]*\") */$1/g
```

Note that this won't handle any kind of escapes inside the quotes.